# Почему если в zSize или в xSise число будет больше чем 255, то весь меш ломается?

Tags: c#, unity3d

(Может найдётся человек, который мне поможет)
Создаю меш с помощью этого скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshCreatorV2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;
    Vector2[] uv;

    public float cellSize;
    public int xSize;
    public int zSize;

    float sample;
    public float multiplier;
    public float perlinSize;
    public float xOffset;
    public float yOffset;
    void Awake()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        MakeDiscreteProceduralGrid();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            MakeDiscreteProceduralGrid();
            UpdateMesh();
        }
    }


    void MakeDiscreteProceduralGrid()
    {
        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];
        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

        for(int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                sample = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * (cellSize / 10) * perlinSize + xOffset, z * (cellSize / 10) * perlinSize + yOffset);
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x * (cellSize / 10), sample * multiplier, z * (cellSize / 10));
                i++;
            }
        }

        int v = 0;
        int t = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                triangles[t + 0] = v + 0;
                triangles[t + 1] = v + xSize + 1;
                triangles[t + 2] = v + 1;
                triangles[t + 3] = v + 1;
                triangles[t + 4] = v + xSize + 1;
                triangles[t + 5] = v + xSize + 2;
                v++;
                t += 6;
            }
            v++;
        }
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.uv = uv;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```

Все public переменные я ввожу в инспекторе. При любых значениях в zSize и xSize от 0 до 255 включительно меш строится нормально и шум Перлина работает хорошо, но если одно из этих значений или оба значения будут 256 или выше, то меш перестанет строиться нормально в сторону и будут появляться полигоны, которые пересекаются с другими полигонами (так быть не должно).
На Unity версии 2019.4.32f1 выдавало ошибку "Expanding invalid MinMaxAABB". На версии Unity 2021.2.1f1 ошибок не выдаёт, но меш и там и там строится неправильно при значениях выше чем 255.
Ссылка на проект:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eeJotJjiQ2ixC4hTRxeo444ZNXGr2nvL?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mesh.indexFormat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html)

> Описание Формат данных буфера индекса сетки.
>
> Индексный буфер может быть 16-битным (поддерживает до 65535 вершин в
> сетке) или 32-битным (поддерживает до 4 миллиардов вершин). Формат
> индекса по умолчанию - 16 бит, так как это требует меньше памяти и
> пропускной способности.
>
> Обратите внимание, что поддержка 32-битных индексов GPU не
> гарантируется на всех платформах; например устройства Android с
> графическим процессором Mali-400 их не поддерживают. При использовании
> 32-битных индексов на такой платформе в журнал будет занесено
> предупреждающее сообщение, и сетка не будет отображаться.
>
> Изменение indexFormat устанавливает subMeshCount в единицу и очищает
> буфер индекса.

Comment: Спасибо! Не ожидал, что мне кто-то поможет.

Comment: Можно было догадаться, что ты столкнулся неким лимитом длинны и гуглить отталкиваясь от этого. У меня это получилось с второго запроса меньше чем за минуту. Уметь составлять запросы это важный навык.